# android: how to zoom in/out and pan images in android viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, imageview

In my android app I have a viewpager with lot of images.

I want to add the functionality of zoom in/out and pan the images. How to do it?

I saw that many people asked this question. I saw their answers. It looks like there are many good libraries. But most of the questions were answered one or two years back.

So what is the suggested way to achieve this.

Comment: Use this library : https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: i wii try it and check